# Bash script doesn't read entire line

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

First off, I am in the early stages of learning bash shell scripting, so I apologize if I say / do anything that doesn't make sense.

Currently, I'm trying to have an SBC, a Khadas VIM3 specifically, run a python script to find and label faces in any given video from a local server. Currently, I need to reduce the frame rate and resolution of the video, which is where the bash script comes into play. I need to automate this process and thought I'd do it using a bash script and crontab. 
The file paths are found and output into a file from  a separate script, and are read by the bash script. The problem comes when I try and call ffmpeg to use the file paths.

**The Code :**

```
pathFile="/home/khadas/Documents/paths"

while IFS= read -r line
do
        ffmpeg -i "$line" -vf scale=960:540 -y "$line"
        cp "$line" ./
done < $pathFile
```

**The resulting error :**

```
: No such file or directoryalRecognition/10/14-53.h264+/2019-09-26-10-14-53.mp4
cp: cannot stat '/home/khadas/Downloads/FacialRecognition/10/14-53.h264+/2019-09-26-10-14-53.mp4'$'\r': No such file or directory
```

**Example of the paths file (There will be hundreds of entries) :**

```
/home/khadas/Downloads/FacialRecognition/10/14-42.h264+/2019-09-26-10-14-42.mp4
/home/khadas/Downloads/FacialRecognition/10/59-06.h264+/2019-09-26-10-59-06.mp4
/home/khadas/Downloads/FacialRecognition/10/36-28.h264+/2019-09-26-10-36-28.mp4
/home/khadas/Downloads/FacialRecognition/10/14-53.h264+/2019-09-26-10-14-53.mp4
```

When using a trimmed down version, the script works as expected. Could it be an issue with the length of the lines? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: According to the error message, `cp` is attempting to access a file whose name ends with `.mp4'$'\r'`.  That appears to means that somewhere there are DOS/Windows-style line-endings.  If you have the `dos2unix` utility, run it against your files including `/home/khadas/Documents/paths`.

Comment: You were correct! I ran docs2unix, then the scripts and it ran as intended. I am curious as to why it developed that DOS/Windows-style line ending to begin with since the file was generated in Linux.  Edit : I had uploaded the file to a Windows host before loading it on the VIM3, could that have caused it?

Comment: Did the `.mp4` files originally come from a pre-OSX Mac? (pre-OSX default line endings were `'\r'` alone) They also used to do some strange stuff with filenames.

Comment: No the file paths where all generated via a python script I made on the VIM3. Upon further inspection, I had put "\r\n" in the f.write section of the script since that's the only way I know to get f.write() to print line per line instead of directly after each thing it writes. That must be the cause, so I'll start looking into other ways to do this, or maybe just implement that fix into the original script.

Answer (score 0):

> According to the error message, `cp` is attempting to access a file whose name ends with `.mp4'$'\r'`. That appears to means that somewhere there are DOS/Windows-style line-endings. If you have the `dos2unix` utility, run it against your files including `/home/khadas/Documents/paths`.

-- [John1024](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3030305/john1024)